# Returning an array object from a for each loop and impleting it to a new loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```js
<!--- for loop that i have tried --->
<script >
var something = $('textarea[id^="alllthedesc"]');
  $(something).each(function () {
    var innervalue = $(this).val();
    if (innervalue.length > 0) {
        return innervalue
    };
  });
  console.log(innervalue); <
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> //textarea
<!--- textarea --->

<div class="container">
    <textarea name="alllthedesc1" id="alllthedesc1">
        this is some text for the first one </textarea>
    <textarea name="alllthedesc2" id="alllthedes2">
        this is some text for number 2 </textarea>
    <textarea name="alllthedesc3" id="alllthedesc3">
        this is some text for the number 3 </textarea>
</div>
```

I have the following structure of text areas which must be placed into an array and used for an alert later i.e. the alert will go through the loop and display each text message which satisfies a certain condition. I have tried a for loop, however the for loop is not returning a value as I want it to. 
Below is what I have tried

```
<!--- bootstrap --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> //textarea
<!--- textarea --->

<div class="container">
    <textarea name="alllthedesc1" id="alllthedesc1">
        this is some text for the first one </textarea>
    <textarea name="alllthedesc2" id="alllthedes2">
        this is some text for number 2 </textarea>
    <textarea name="alllthedesc3" id="alllthedesc3">
        this is some text for the number 3 </textarea>
</div>


<!--- for loop that i have tried --->
<script >
var something = $('textarea[id^="alllthedesc"]');
  $(something).each(function () {
    var innervalue = $(this).val();
    if (innervalue.length > 0) {
        return innervalue
    };
  });
  console.log(innervalue); <
</script>    
<!--- Jquery --->
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>
```

Comment: please add related html.

Comment: place a variable outside to hold the return value and set it inside loop

Answer (score 1):

Just use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method instead of [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method, so that you can return value from iteration.

```
var something =  $('textarea[id^="alllthedesc"]');

//you need to use map() instead of each() method because each() does not return any value

var innervalue = something.map(function() { 
    if ($(this).val().length > 0){return $(this).val()};
}); // in innervalue you will get all the values
```

Comment: returns [object, Object] which was essentialy what i had earlier

Comment: Actually, there was a mistake in my answer, now updated..!

Comment: that seems to do it. thanks. so map creates an entirely new array ? and can the var innervalue now be spliced anyway ? so that the variable can be alerted with the first index first and so on, as a series of alerts ?

Comment: Yeah..! You can read more about [map() method here](http://api.jquery.com/map/)..!

Comment: Map is something i was unfamiliar with and it makes the for loop so much more powerful. I will definately start using map() a lot more now.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable 'var innervalue' inside the loop and used it outside the loop. Declare the variable outside the loop if you want to use it outside as follows.

```
 var innervalue;
    $(something).each(function() { 
    innervalue= $(this).val();
    console.log(innervalue);
    if (innervalue.length > 0){return innervalue};

    });
    console.log(innervalue);
```